# Video Playback is halting after updating ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, video, smplayer

Today I updated the long pending list of softwares in Ubuntu 14.04, including SM Player. The updated version of SM Player is 16.8. Earlier it was version 16.7.

Now all my video files are not playing smoothly. Video stops and audio keeps on playing. Also when I close the player the audio keeps on playing for some seconds.

I don't know what may have the problem. May be some codecs have also been updated .

Also Default Video player of Ubuntu is behaving the same. I also installed MPV and VLC but to no use, same behavior.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! In my case, in the Sound Settings -> output , a virtual "Simultaneously Output On All Local Cards" Output was selected, which was added by Pulse Audio. I disabled it from Pulse Audio Preferences and now its normal again.